# Select Multiple Tuple Items With Easygui's multchoicebox

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, tuples, easygui

I'm using `easygui.multchoicebox()` to select a number of items in a tuple.  How do I make a conditional that executes code when certain items from the tuple are selected?

Here is example code that does not work (nothing is returned):

```
from easygui import *

fieldnames = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"]
choice = multchoicebox("Pick an option.", "", fieldnames)
if choice == fieldnames[0,1]:
    msgbox('Incomplete')
if choice == fieldnames[2]:
    msgbox('Complete')
```

It says that the list indices cannot be tuples.  I changed the conditionals to strings and it did not work either (still nothing is returned):

```
from easygui import *

fieldnames = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"]
choice = multchoicebox("Pick an option.", "", fieldnames)
if choice == "Yes" and "No":
    msgbox('Incomplete')
if choice == "Maybe":
    msgbox('Complete')
```

What is preventing the code from being executed?  If `easygui.multchoicebox()` isn't designed from this, what module is?

Answer (score 2):

You say

```
fieldnames[0, 1]
```

Essentially, you're passing a tuple `(0, 1)` as an index to `fieldnames`. Use this idiom instead:

```
if choice in fieldnames[0:2]:
    #dostuff
```